# How to control children entity shadows?

Tags: aframe

I am running into issues where I parent entities and set certain attributes, such as shadows, on the parent and its children (different values). It appears the object3Dset event bubbles and anything the child (or when any other child triggers the object3dset event) is overwritten by the parent (as it sets all children to its value automatically: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/shadow.js ). Is there a standardized way to handle this behaviour?

Here is the "hello aframe" example to simplify:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>

      <a-entity light="type:directional; castShadow:true;" position="1 1 1"></a-entity>

      <!-- parent that shadows -->
      <a-entity shadow="cast:true; receive:true">

        <!-- children that avoid shadows -->
        <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow="cast:false; receive:false"></a-box>
        <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow="cast:false; receive:false"></a-sphere>
        <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow="cast:false; receive:false"></a-cylinder>
        <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow="cast:false; receive:false"></a-plane>
      </a-entity>

      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Shadows :(
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To work around this issue I had to remake the shadow component to have a flag to control if children are also affected. Would be curious to hear if there is a better way to do this.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('custom-shadow', {
    schema: {
        cast:               {type: 'boolean',    default: true},
        receive:            {type: 'boolean',    default: true},
        applyToChildren:    {type: 'boolean',    default: true}

    },
    multiple: false, //do not allow multiple instances of this component on this entity
    init: function() {
        this.applyShadow();
        this.el.addEventListener('object3dset', this.applyShadow.bind(this));
    },
    applyShadow : function () {
        const data    = this.data;
        const mesh    = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');

        if (!mesh) return;

            mesh.traverse(function (node) {
                node.castShadow     = data.cast;
                node.receiveShadow  = data.receive;

                if (data.applyToChildren) {
                    return;
                }
            });
    },
    update: function (oldData) {
        this.applyShadow.bind(this);
    }
});
```